# Calculating points visibility in 3D space

Tags: java, 3d, camera, lwjgl

I am experimenting with **LWJGL2** and I want to be able to tell if the camera is able to see a certain point in **3D space**. I was trying on my own to see if I could do it, and ended up with something that kinda works and only for rotation on the Y axis.

This code works, but not in both axes. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it either.

```
public boolean isInFrame(float x, float y, float z){ //The z isn't used

    float camera = rotation.y; //The cameras y rotation
    double object = Math.atan2(y, x)*(180/Math.PI);

    object += (180 - camera);
    if (object <0 ) object += 360;
    if (object >360 ) object -= 360;

    return 270>object&&90<object; //set to 180˚ for test


}
```

For the code, I am assuming the camera is centered around 0,0,0.

I just want to know how I could change this so that it works for **x and y rotation of the camera**. For example, it could tell me if if a point is visible regardless of the cameras rotation.

**NOTE:**
I am not worrying about anything obstructing the view of the point.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the view and projection matrices of the camera (let's call them `V`, `P`), you can just apply the transformations to your point and check whether the result lies within the clip volume of the camera.

Say your point is at `(x, y, z)`. Construct a vector `p = (x, y, z, 1)` and apply the camera transform to it:

```
q = P * V * p
```

The view transform `V` applies the transformation of the world relative to the camera,  based on the camera position and orientation. Then, the projection `P` deforms the camera's view frustum (i.e., the visible space of the camera) into a unit cube, like this:

[image]
(Image source: [Song Ho Ahn](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html))

In order to read off the coordinate values of the resulting point, we must first de-homogenize it by dividing by its `w` component:

```
r = q / q.w
```

Now, the components `r.x`, `r.y`, `r.z` tell you whether the point lies within the visible range of the camera:

- If `r.x < -1`, the point lies beyond the left border of the screen.
- If `r.x > 1`, the point lies beyond the right border of the screen.
- If `r.y < -1`, the point lies beyond the bottom border of the screen.
- If `r.y > 1`, the point lies beyond the top border of the screen.
- If `r.z < -1`, the point lies beyond the near plane of the camera, i.e., the point is behind the camera or too close for the camera to see.
- If `r.z > 1`, the point lies beyond the far plane of the camera, i.e., the point is too far away for the camera to see.
- Otherwise, the point is in the visible range of the camera.

Comment: I understand what your saying here, but i am not sure I know how to get the view and projection matrices from LWJGL2. In LWJGL2 all you do is define it like this: 

`glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
gluPerspective((float) 100, 640f / 480f, 0.01f, 100);`

how do i get the raw matrix from that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with LWJGL in particular. In plain OpenGL, the state of the matrix stack is accessible via e.g. `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)` and `glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, ...)`, which return arrays of 16 floats.

Comment: hey, great answer! one question: what is `q.w` (`w` component)?